# Firebase putData function

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Xcode, Swift 3.
I am trying to call putData for an image (PNG), and this is my code :

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("ProductsImages").child(product.UniqueID()).child("MainImage.png")
    if let mainChosenImage = self.selectedImageToUpload
    {
        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mainChosenImage)
        {
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
                {
                    (StorageMetaData, error) in
                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }

                    self.mainImageURL = StorageMetaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            })
        }
    }
```

And the behavior is this - the image is saved fine to Firebase, but "completion" isn't called. Meaning - it won't check if error != nil, and more importantly - it won't instantiate mainImageURL with the absolute URL string.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

completion should look like this

```
 if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!) {
    storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")

        } else {

            // your uploaded photo url.
        }
   }
```

Comment: How does this code work ? It doesn't know what completion is because it's not defined .

Comment: "Missing argument label 'Completion' in call"

Comment: Wait, I have a function overload. Let me try that

Comment: It does, however, get to the "else" after a really long whole. Do you know of a better way to tackle this ?

Comment: Actually this depends on image size and the current network speed

Comment: Ok, good to know this. I guess it takes a while because I'm on a VM. Thanks !