# Store Downloaded Gif in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gif

I am using the `Giphy API` and `FLAnimatedImage` respository to fetch and show gifs. Is there a way to store selected gifs to `firebase` or `firestore` that I can then fetch later?

My reason is to avoid the intensive task of re-downloading the gif. Would it be storing the bytes of the `Data` object?

I understand I could probably just store the gif url and then when I need the gif, to query the string and re-download, but I'm hoping to again avoid that if there's a way.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
let url = URL(string: gifUrlString)!
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
let image = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: imageData)
```

Comment: I had answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644560/swift2-retrieving-images-from-firebase/34044446#34044446) back in 2015 - that code shows how to store and retrieve a .jpg to/from Firebase. The thing that is confusing as you want to *avoid the intensive task of re-downloading the gif* - if you are storing it in Firebase you will have to re-download it. Additionally, Firebase Realtime Database is *not* the best solution for storing images - Firebase has [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start) which is perfect for that task.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the message. if you'll allow me as im not super handy in this, i had thought perhaps if we already downloaded the gif and had it in bytes, and potentially storing that, all that's left in terms of a future task is to fetch the bytes from Firebase and then render it into the gif versus calling and re-downloading from the api. let me know if that changes anything or not, thanks!

Comment: If you *fetch the bytes from Firebase*, you are downloading the bytes from Firebase which is exactly the same thing as downloading the gif from Firebase. Bytes are bytes either way. Also. *rendering to a gif* is just a set of bytes and there is no rendering involved. Not sure what *re-downloading from the API* means as 'downloading' is what Firebase does. It's an online real-time database and any interactions with it are downloaded/uploaded. The exception is if you have a temporary disconnection which is where persistence comes in. Maybe you are thinking that Firebase is a local database?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data of the image

```
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
```

with [Firebase putData function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703188/firebase-putdata-function)

but you still need to download it again with firebase getData , so you may create a simple database structure in your app with CoreData / Realm associate each gif say with timestamp of it's download , then upload it to Firebase and update your local database with these data

**BTW** avoid using `Data(contentsOf` as it blocks the main thread until the date grabbed so use it inside a background thread